# Printing only the contents of an iframe when a user selects file->print

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, printing

**Problem:**

I have an application which loads content from other servers into an `<iframe>`.  Users want to be able to print the content in the iframe, which can sometimes be quite long and cause the iframe to scroll.  When the print, only the area shown in the iframe's viewport is printed.  The rest is cut off.

**What I've tried:**

Using `@media print` styles, I can hide all the other elements on the page and expand the iframe to 100% width and height.  What I can't do AFAICT is resize it to the w/h of the actual content (using CSS alone), so if 100% isn't enough the content is truncated.

I know this is solvable via javascript, but browsers do not consistently offer an event hook for file->print, so I can't run the javascript when it's needed.

I could make a custom "print" button, so that the JS could run and the iframe would be correctly printed, but it doesn't allow for "Print Preview", because browsers don't offere a JS method for this.

I'm stumped here, is there an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the contents of your iframe you can use

```
document.getElementById('ifr1').contentWindow.print()
```

This will call the `print()` on the contents of the iframe (and not the container window).

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. Users want to use File->print or print preview, and I need to be able to hook into that and display only the iframe contents.

Comment: `File->print` will print the "parent" window. If you must use this - the only option that you have is to set the position of the iframe in 0-0 (top-left corner), set the width of the iframe to the window's width, and set the iframe's height to the height of it's content. This is the only way you can really print/preview the window and the actual "output" will be the entire content of the iframe.

Comment: Correct, but in order to do that, I need a way to run a JS function when the user prints or requests a print preview.  There doesn't seem to be a consistent way to do this.